# ssrs how to remove particular rows conditionally

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

In my ssrs report, I have a column "Total" and it contains integer values.
Now I want to remove the entire row from report, where value of column Total = -1.

Comment: how do you get the `Total`? from sql query or the ssrs?

Comment: from sql query..but I cannot modify the sql code...

Comment: you cannot modify the query from the datasets?

Comment: I can modify the dataset..but the query is quite complex and already tested..so don't want to take the risk of altering query.

Comment: paste your query, should be a way to add `where` condition to it

Comment: Set row viability false if textbox that represents Total is 1. ReportItems!Total.value

Answer (score 0):

If you can't filter the data from the query, you can do so either via the tablix properties or the dataset properties. To add a filter to your dataset, right click the Dataset name and select "Dataset properties". Similarly, you can modify the tablix properties by right clicking the small square in the corner of your tablix and selecting "Tablix properties". Then select "Filters" and add your desired filter. See image:[image]

Comment: While this is correct, it's not very helpful because you didn't explain how to do this. If he already knew how to filter data in the dataset properties he probably wouldn't have asked this question.